# re define document_root when including an html file in subfolder

Tags: php

When browsing my website, the user will land on:

> mysite.com/index.php

I would like to include a complete html file from a subfolder and not use an iframe.

for example, in the directory you will find:

> www/index.php (the file the user is browsing)
>   www/subfolder/otherpage.html (the page to be included
>   www/subfolder/images/something.jpg (an asset of the subfolder)

When I include `otherpage.html` from within the root folder none of the paths are correct.

My question is: how do I reset the ROOT to be `mysite.com/subfolder/` so that `otherpage.html` can be included correctly from within `index.php`?

Complete `index.php`:

```
<?php

include('subfolder/otherpage.html');

?>
```

Comment: If you look at most large packages, they have constants defined with stuff like application root, images dir, uploads dir...etc. Then you include a file like: `include(APPLICATION_ROOT.'/whatever.php')`This is the suggested method. Other things you can do, chdir will change php's working directory so that relatively included files will be from that or you can change the include path which is a list of paths php looks for files that are included.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? SO will not provide you with a readymade script.
You may want to use constants or variables.. or if you really can't change the otherpage.html you may want to replace the path manually.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'subfolder/otherpage.html';
$output = ob_get_contents();
$output = str_replace( 'mysite.com/', 'mysite.com/subfolder/', $output );
print $output;
?>
```